# Ошибка cs0246The type or namespace name 'NavMeshAgent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

Нужна ваша помощь, я абсолютный ноль в программировании, но все же решил попробовать. В общем, задача проще некуда, включил урок на ютубе, дай думаю повторю, там парень писал скрипт для паука, чтобы он преследовал игрока и наносил урон, я писал код один в один, по итогу у него все работает и ошибок нет, а у меня одна критическая ошибка, из-за чего она вылезла непонятно, ссылается на 5 и 9 строчки кода (если я правильно понял). Вот текст ошибки: The type or namespace name 'NavMeshAgent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Вот сам код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
{
    const float DAMAGE = 0.2f;
    Animator animator;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    GameObject player;
    Player health;

    float visible = 4f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        if (player != null) 
        {
            health = player.GetComponent<Player>();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        if (player != null)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position);
            if (distance < 1f)
            {
                health.Damage(DAMAGE);
            } 
            else if (distance < visible)
            {
                agent.destination = player.transform.position;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: "я абсолютный ноль в программировании" - Вы меня развеселили. +1 Вам за это.

Comment: абсолютный ноль - это `0xfffffeef`

Comment: @aepot а если по Кельвину?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
```